# How to force a full reload of a page after a POST

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am using class based view with a get and a post methods

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        #some code
    def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        #update some data which is used in the view
        return redirect('app:my-view')
```

the problem with this is that django does not re-execute the `get` method after the redirect (the GET request can be confirmed in firebug). If I hit `F5` manually in the browser, I can see the modified data.

This is probably a cache issue, but want to update the page but if the page is no reloaded in the GET after the POST, I can't do this.

Comment: You are not issuing an ajax request, right?

Comment: for the POST, yes it is.

Comment: Then the page won't be redirected with this, only the ajax request would be redirected. If you want to reload after successful post request with ajax, you need to do that on the client side.

Comment: Instead of this `redirect('app:my-view')` use `return redirect('app:my-view')`

Comment: @ShafikurRahman, I forgot to write the return but I am using it. I updated my question. thanks

Comment: @OzgurAkcali, I don't get it. After the POST I see the GET request with 200 status. What do you mean by "only the ajax request would be redirected"?

Comment: You see it on the network tab of Firebug, right? That's because your redirect works, after the post is successful, request is redirected with a get request. But that is your ajax request being re-directed, and that won't change the browser url.

Comment: @fccoelho I've posted an answer with more information

Comment: Got it. Now I doing the redirection from the ajax side. thanks @OzgurAkcali.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirect actually works, but as you are issuing the request with **Ajax**, your browser is not redirected, only your ajax request is being re-directed, and that won't change the page url in the browser.

That's actually the whole point of ajax requests, you exchange information with the server without changing the browser url. Anything you do with ajax requests have no effect on browser url.

If you post an html form instead, without ajax, to this url, your post method would be executed, and then your page would be redirected with a get request.

To do what you want with ajax, I suggest you do not redirect at the end of your post request, but return a success response. Then, on the client side, issue an ajax request, and reload the page on your request's success handler.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this You have to redirect from the Ajax call:

```
$.post("",{active: status,
        success: function(){
          window.location = "";
        },
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken':jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()});
```

This is done by the `window.location="";` I am passing an empty string because I am redirecting to the same page, but you can pass any url.